# PHP Login with Materialize CSS Modal

Tags: php, authentication, materialize

I've built a login system with PHP and I'm styling it with Materialize CSS. For login, I'm using a popup modal. The login works fine, but I want to ***stop the close and display my error message if login attempt fails.*** The PHP error message pops up correctly, but the modal closes every time. If I click back into it, I can see the error message - however - I need the close to stop unless they hit "close" or the login/redirect is successful. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: You must provide some code.

Answer (score 1):

Does your button include `class="modal-close"`?

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


  <!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">This Button CLOSES the Modal On Click</a>
      <a href="#!" class="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">This Button DOES NOT close On Click</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the options provided. Use dismissible false, then close it yourself manually after. I used jquery but you can also use without jquery as shown between comment lines

```js
/*document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    options = [{
    'dismissible': false,
    }];
    var instances = M.Modal.init(elems, options);
  });
*/
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal({'dismissible': false});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```